# how replace server repo file by my local repo in Git..?

Tags: git, github

My problem is in my git repo there are some files..but when i commit if then due to..

```
git config core.autocrlf
this is true by default..
```

so in hex of every file it replace `0A  as 0D 0A` i did commit . But after knowing this problem i change ..

```
git config core.autocrlf , as false
```

But now the problem is if i push then its showing

```
every thing is up to date.
```

I know that ok, But i have to push my new code now coz of this hex code problem in every file..
So who i con do this....

Thank's..!!

Answer (score 1):

You could try, (if the push is fairly recent and nobody has yet pulled that specific commit) to:

- amend your latest commit (by changing its comment for instance)
- `git push -force master origin` in order to *erase* the latest commit on GitHub by your new commit, with this time the conversions being avoided.